# SVN sync issue:Revision being currently copied (237266), last merged revision (237265), and destination HEAD (237264) are inconsistent;

Tags: svn, synchronization

We used to sync code from one server to another sever.
Yesterday I found an issue.

property 'svn:sync-lock' deleted from repository revision 0
svnsync sync https://slc-svn.accela.com/svn/projects --non-interactive
svnsync: Revision being currently copied (237266), last merged revision (237265), and destination HEAD (237264) are inconsistent; have you committed to the destination without using svnsync?

How to start to sync from revision 237265 instead of 237266?
The repository is so huge(at least 100G) and I do not want to export the dump or sync the repository again...
Could you help provide one solution?
Thx!